# Google Adsense Formatting Issue

Tags: javascript, css, adsense

I would like to put two adsense ads next to each other, side by side. The problem is that google seems to have added a left-margin, and no way to get rid of it. I've looked around and other people have had the same problem but no good solution has been presented.

Does anybody know a good way to macgyver the margin away? I've tried moving it with position:relative inside a div, but it doesn't work well cross-system.

Comment: How is the `margin-left` style applied? Can't you just neuter it with your own CSS rule?

Comment: No, It's displayed through javascript so you can't see what to select.

Comment: Actually, you can with the developer tools / Firebug. Try examining their `Inspect Element` feature after the ad is created. You should see the element's markup and the styles that apply to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how adsense ads work but can you over ride their styling in your css by usinging `!important` ?

E.g `margin-left:100px !important;`